# Unable to update post using models in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I want to prepare a webpage which outputs book name, publisher and author and want to add the data dynamically using admin panel but unable to do it using below code. Please help

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class researchpaper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publication = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    authors = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def publications(request):
    context = {
            'researchposts': researchpaper.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'lab/publications.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
path('publications', views.publications, name='publications'),
```

html file

```
 {% for paper in object_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h5>2021</h5>
                        <p style="color: black;"><b>{{paper.title}}1. A minimal model for synaptic integration in simple neurons</b></p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;"><i>Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena, 2021</i></p>
                        <p style="font-size: 14px;"><i>Adrian Alva, Harjinder Singh.</i></p>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#"
                            target="blank" style="color: dodgerblue;"><i class="ai ai-google-scholar-square ai-2x"
                                style="padding-right: 10px;"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <hr>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should object_list in your template be researchposts since that's the key you provide in context?

```
{% for paper in researchposts %}
...
```

Comment: ok, i have changed but, when ever i add data in the admin panel it is not reflecting in html page?

Comment: after refreshing the page? Is any paper data displaying on the html page? What can you see on the html page?

Comment: after refreshing every thing in the text field is disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your views.py as:

```
def publications(request):
    researchposts = researchpaper.objects.values('title', 'publications', 'author')
    return render(request, 'lab/publications.html', {'researchposts':researchposts})
```

In your html file (lab/publications.html):

```
{% for text in researchposts %}
Name: {{ text.title }} <br>
Pub: {{ text.publications }} <br>
Author: {{ text.author }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```